# jquery integration with coldfusion cfc and checkbox form

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, cfc

I am new to jquery and want to accomplish the following.
1) Generate and show a form when a button is clicked

2) Have the user use checkboxes on that form to indicate who they want to send the email to

3) For every checked box in the dialog box, use cfmail to email said person (I can write this part)

Please see the start of my code below.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#notifyregs").click(function() {
        var initialDiv = this;
       // HELP - set the checked box values

        var reminderemails = $(this).data("reminderemails");
        var count = 0;

        $("#editForm").dialog({ width: 500, height: 'auto', maxHeight: 1000,
            buttons: {
                "Send Emails": function() {
                    var thisDialog = $(this);
                   // HELP - Loop through reminderemails and send each value to the function sendreminders
                    $.post("tsafunctions.cfc", {
                        method: 'sendreminders',
                    reminderemails: $("#reminderemails").val(), 
                        }, 
                    function() {
                        $("#message").show();
                        $("#message").text('You sent reminders to ' + count + ' athletes');
                        $(thisDialog).dialog("close");
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

The Form

```
  <div id="editForm" title="Notify Incomplete Registrations">
  Check who to send emails to:<br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="reminderemails" value="123456" checked="checked" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="reminderemails" value="234567" checked="checked" /></td>
</div>
```

Comment: wrap them in a form tag and use `serialize()` for the whole form

Comment: Is your intent to use jquery for something or to do something useful?  If it's the latter, there are better ways to accomplish that goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
selectedEmails=jQuery('#editForm :checkbox:checked').serialize();
```

In your jQuery.post there is a data option for passing data:

```
$.post("tsafunctions.cfc", {data:selectedEmails, ...});
```

Comment: thanks, that worked.  How do I parse out the reminderemails=107022&reminderemails=114281&reminderemails=107396&reminderemails=112360&reminderemails=122390 format to just get a comma separated list of values?

Comment: Post your code, if you do it the way I showed, jQuery should pass it correctly. did you dump what CF is receiving?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, it appears that you want to make a request to the $.post function for each selected checkbox. If you don't want to parse the serialized data, you would need something like this:

```
//--collect the checked input values and store in array
var reArr = [];
$('#editForm input:checked').each(function(){
   /*--
     pushes the value of each checkbox control that 
     is checked within the #editForm Div into and array
   --*/
  reArr.push($(this).val()); 
});

//--loop through the array and make your requests
for(var i=0; i < reArr.length; i++ ){
   /*--
    access each of the array elements using array syntax (e.g. reArr[i])
   --*/
   console.log(reArr[i]) 
   $.post("tsafunctions.cfc", {"reminderemails":reArr[i]} );
 }
 console.log(reArr);
```